# How to Sort Values on the Graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using python to analyze **911 Call for Service** dataset. I'm showing data monthwise. Data is not sorted Date Wise.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('911_calls_for_service.csv')
r, c = df.shape

df['callDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['callDateTime'])
df['MonthYear'] = df['callDateTime'].apply(lambda time: str(time.year) + '-' + str(time.month))
df['MonthYear'].value_counts().plot()
print(df['MonthYear'].value_counts())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('911_calls_for_service.csv')
df['callDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['callDateTime'])

ax = df['callDateTime'].groupby([df["callDateTime"].dt.year, df["callDateTime"].dt.month]).count().plot()
ax.set_xlabel("Date")
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]